# SCCM - what is required to prepare an installer

Tags: deployment, sccm

I've been asked by a client if it is possible to prepare our product for deployment via SSCM. Currently we produce an msi installer; is that what SCCM would need or do we need to do something to the msi package to make it SCCM friendly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're most likely asking you to make sure your product can be installed without any user interaction required.  Since it's already an msi, you've got nothing to worry about unless you've done a very poor job at making the msi and included custom actions that popup separate dialogs that can't be turned off.

Basically, if you can install your msi with silent options like */qn* or */qb* and not be required to touch it before it's done installing, you're golden.

*Edit: I just thought of another caveat.  If your application requires activation, ideally that activation should have the option of being included as part of the install process.  At a worst case, it should at least be doable by limited-rights end-users.  Essentially, everything that your application needs elevated access to do should have the ability to be automated during the install process.